# Centering Font Awsome in the middle of the screen

Tags: css, font-awesome

[In this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps3331333/tv2kob5g/1/) I have a spinning Font Awsome in the top-left corner. How to display it in the middle of the screen (vertically and horizontally) ?

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a padding of 50% and a margin of -8px (50% of its original size). The `body` must span over the whole window. To prevent strange behavior of the scroll bar (due to the animation attached to .fa-spin) use these styles on a container:

```
<div class="center-all">
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</div>
```

The css is as follows:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.center-all {
  padding: 50%;
  margin: -8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/82z3t8dL/3/

Comment: Why do I need to specify 100% in body and html?

Comment: The 50% for .fa-spin is relative to its container (`body` in this case), so that it is necessary to cover the window. `html` must be set to 100% as well because it is the parent of the `body` tag and the 100% of `body` corresponds to the size of `html`

Comment: The problem I found is that since the position is not absolute then the spin pushes down the other elements. In this jsfiddle I added the `position:absolute` to the css, but I see a strange behavior, the scrolls change size by themselves. I tried this in IE and Chrome. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/ps3331333/82z3t8dL/2/

Comment: This comes from the rotation of the spinner (try it by adding some background-color to .fa-spin). You can prevent this by wrapping the spinner in a div, which then gets the style to be centered. I will update my fiddle, so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Did this answer help? Then please be so kind, mark it as solved.

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work because the spinner should be absolute in the middle of the screen (like a loading icon to notify the user they have to wait). In this example the divs push down the icon, and they shouldn't https://jsfiddle.net/ps3331333/82z3t8dL/6/

Comment: Then add `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` to the `.center-all` definition and it's done.